# LiveWallpaper Background

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

i have problem with live wallpaper on preview mode.ie the wallpaper image doesn't fit well in landscape mode.it works great on portrait.i need your help.hope you would help me.i have added code

RajawaliRenderer.java

```
public class RipplesRenderer extends RajawaliRenderer {
    private final int NUM_CUBES_H = 4;
    private final int NUM_CUBES_V = 4;
    private final int NUM_CUBES = NUM_CUBES_H * NUM_CUBES_V;
    //private Animation3D[] mAnims;
    private TouchRippleFilter mFilter;
    private long frameCount;
    private final int QUAD_SEGMENTS = 40;
    int mScreenHeight,
    mScreenWeight;
    Gallery_Activity mm;
    boolean flag_check = false;
    int pos = 0;
    int viewBackgroundImageName;
    Bitmap texture;
    SimpleMaterial planeMat;
    int randPosition=1;

    int change_value;
    int Ripple_number,speed1;
    Preferences preferences;

    private MediaPlayer myplayer;
    private boolean sound;

    public RipplesRenderer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFrameRate(50);
        this.mContext=context;

        randPosition = BitmapUpdate.randomGenerator;
        texture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.gthree_one);
        //sp=mContext.getSharedPreferences("wallpapersettings",0);
        preferences=new Preferences(mContext);
    }

    protected void initScene() {

        if(randPosition!=1) {
            texture = BitmapUpdate.bit;
        }

        mCamera.setPosition(0, 0, -9);

        DirectionalLight light = new DirectionalLight(0, 0, 1);
        light.setPower(1f);

        BaseObject3D group = new BaseObject3D();
        DiffuseMaterial material = new DiffuseMaterial();
        material.setUseColor(true);
        mScreenHeight = GNWallpaper.hieght;

        mScreenWeight = GNWallpaper.weight;
        Random rnd = new Random();        

        planeMat = new SimpleMaterial();
        Plane plane=new Plane(9,7,1,1);

        //Plane plane = new Plane(4, 4, 1, 1);
        plane.setRotZ(-90);
        plane.setScale(1.0f);
        plane.setMaterial(planeMat);
        addChild(plane);

        mFilter = new TouchRippleFilter();

        mPostProcessingRenderer.setQuadSegments(QUAD_SEGMENTS);
        mPostProcessingRenderer.setQuality(PostProcessingQuality.MEDIUM);
        addPostProcessingFilter(mFilter);
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        if (pos != com.themebowlapp.galaxynote3livewallpaper.Gallery_Activity.wallpaper_position || randPosition != BitmapUpdate.randomGenerator) {
            texture = BitmapUpdate.bit;
            pos = com.themebowlapp.galaxynote3livewallpaper.Gallery_Activity.wallpaper_position;
            randPosition = BitmapUpdate.randomGenerator;
        }

        Ripple_number=preferences.getSpeed_controler();

        speed1=Ripple_number*100;
        super.onSurfaceCreated(gl, config);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
        super.onDrawFrame(glUnused);

        mFilter.setTime((float) frameCount++ *.05f);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        super.onSurfaceChanged(gl, width, height);
        mFilter.setScreenSize(width, height);
        mFilter.setRippleSize((40+speed1));
        planeMat.addTexture(mTextureManager.addTexture(texture));
    }

    public void setTouch(float x, float y) {
        mFilter.addTouch(x, y, frameCount *.05f);
    }

    @Override
    public void  onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int action = event.getAction();

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {            
            //sound
            myplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.water_drop);
            myplayer.setVolume(100, 100);
            myplayer.start();

            myplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer myplayer) {
                    myplayer.release();
                } 
            });

            setTouch(event.getX() / mScreenWeight, 1.0f - (event.getY() / mScreenHeight));
        }

        super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Settings.java

```
public class Settings extends Activity  {
    public TextView SettingTextObj, BackgroundTextObj;
    private RelativeLayout chose_background;
    public Preferences preferences;
    Context cont = this;
    private CheckBox soundcheckbox;
    private String PREFRENCES_NAME;
    SharedPreferences settings;
    //    private Button choosebackground;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        chose_background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.BackgroundLayoutId);
        BackgroundTextObj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.backgroundTxtViewId);

        soundcheckbox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME, 0);
        Boolean isChecked = settings.getBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", false);
        soundcheckbox.setChecked(isChecked);

        soundcheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            private MediaPlayer myplayer;
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
                Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME, 0).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", isChecked);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                myplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.water_drop);
                myplayer.setVolume(100, 100);
                myplayer.start();
            }
        });


        preferences = new Preferences(cont);

        chose_background.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String[] items = { "Phone Gallery", "Choose Background" };

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Settings.this);
                builder.setTitle("Pick a Background");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (items[item].equals(items[0])) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.this, PhoneGallery_Activity.class));
                        } else {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.this, Gallery_Activity.class));
                        }
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

GNWallpaper.java

```
public class GNWallpaper extends Wallpaper {
    private RipplesRenderer mRenderer;
    private  String imageBg;
    private int cvwidth;
    private int cvheight;
    private int visibleWidth;
    private Bitmap bg;
    private String LoadText;
    private boolean sound;
    private MediaPlayer myplayer;
    public static WindowManager display;
    static int height,width;

    //private Integer[] mImageIds = { R.drawable.gthree_one,R.drawable.gthree_two,R.drawable.gthree_three, R.drawable.gthree_four, R.drawable.gthree_five, R.drawable.gthree_six,};
    private int position;

    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        display =(WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        height= display.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
        width= display.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        mRenderer = new RipplesRenderer(this);

        //Log.i("shibbu"," hello");
        return new WallpaperEngine(this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE), getBaseContext(), mRenderer, false);
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs,
            String key) {

        imageBg = prefs.getString("image_custom", "Bad Image");
        getBackground();

        sound=prefs.getBoolean("pref_sound", false);

        //          //sound
        //            sound=prefs.getBoolean("pref_sound", false);
    }

    void getBackground() {
        if (this.cvwidth == 0 || this.cvheight == 0 || this.visibleWidth == 0) {
            this.cvwidth = 1290;
            this.cvheight = 800;
            this.visibleWidth = 1290;
        }

        if(new File(imageBg).exists()) {
            int SampleSize = 1;

            do {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                bg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageBg, options);
                SampleSize = (int) (Math.ceil(options.outWidth/(this.visibleWidth * 2))*2);
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                try {
                    options.inSampleSize = SampleSize;
                    bg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageBg, options);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    SampleSize = SampleSize * 2;
                }
            } while (bg == null);

            bg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bg, this.cvwidth/2, this.cvheight, true);
        } else {
            bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.gthree_one);
            //bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImageIds[position]);
            //position++;
            bg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bg, this.cvwidth/2, this.cvheight, true);
            LoadText = "";    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @anyone can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link.It will help you to change to landscape view..
http://tips4android.blogspot.in/2012/01/android-tips-how-to-get-screen.html

Comment: My wallpaper do rotate on landscape mode but the problem its in landscape mode the image doesn't fill the screen.

Comment: kindly upload your project in dropbox and send the link..will fix the issue

Comment: That's the code.in RajawaliRenderer.java class something must be done with onSurfaceChanged().